# Clicar no botão Salvar e alterar booleano Django 2.0

Tags: django, booleano

Senhores, estou estudando Django 2.0, e estou com um problema, ao clicar em salvar quero alterar no banco de dados o booleano de **False** para **True**, e não faço a minima idéia de como se faz isso.

Se alguém puder me ajudar?

Segue código resumido:

---

#### models.py

```
from django.db import models

class Espera(models.Model):

   ...

   cancelaEspera = models.BooleanField(default=False,  blank=True)
   obsCancelamentoEspera = models.TextField('Observações', null=True, blank=True)

   def __str__(self):
    return "%s %s" % (self.dataEspera)
```

---

#### form.py

```
from django.forms import ModelForm
from . import models

...

class cancelaEsperaForm(ModelForm):
class Meta:
    model = models.Espera
    fields = ['obsCancelamentoEspera']
```

---

#### view.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect, get_object_or_404
from django.http import HttpResponse, HttpResponseRedirect
from . import models, forms, urls

...

def cancelarEspera(request, id):
    cancela = get_object_or_404(models.Espera, pk=id)
    form = forms.cancelaEsperaForm(request.POST or None, request.FILES or None, instance=cancela)

    if form.is_valid():
        form.save()      
        return redirect('listaEspera')

    return render(request, 'espera//cancelaEspera.html', {'form': form})
```

---

#### template.html

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block main %}

    <div class="card">
        <form method="POST">
            {% csrf_token %}

            <h1> Cancelamento da Espera </h1>

            <p> Qual o motivo do Cancelamento? </p>    

            {{ form|bootstrap }}                        

            <h2> Tem certeza que deseja cancelar essa espera?</h2>

            <button type="submit" > Sim </button>
            <a href="{% url 'listaEspera' %}" method="get" > Não </a>       

        </form>
    </div>

{% endblock %}
```

Comment: Dentro de form você deve informar quais campos serão apresentados na página, e você só informou o campo `obsCancelamentoEspera`

Comment: meu **form.py** é muito grande achei desnecessário colocar ele inteiro, por isso as reticencias, resolvi ir direto ao problema. Mas se for realmente necessário, eu coloco ḿais dados.

Comment: você colocou `fields = ['obsCancelamentoEspera']`, faltou colocar o `cancelaEspera` dentro dessa lista.

Comment: @Paulo, colocando no `fields` o `cancelaEspera` só aparecerá uma caixa de seleção no template para marcação da conclusão. Não quero uma caixa de seleção, quero clicar no botão **SIM** e o `cancelaEspera` se torna **True** automaticamente, sem marcação em caixa de seleção.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Se você quer apenas alterar o valor do campo `BooleanField`, altere dessa forma:

```
if form.is_valid():
    form_ = form.save(commit=False)
    form_.cancela = True
    form_.save()
    return redirect('listaEspera')
```

Comment: funcionou, obrigado, só fiz a alteração:
**Na linha 3:**
`form_.cancelaEspera = True`